# SQL Server: How to allow duplicate records on small table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, duplicates

I have a small table "`ImgViews`" that only contains two columns, an ID column called "`imgID`" + a count column called "`viewed`", both set up as int.

The idea is to use this table only as a counter so that I can track how often an image with a certain ID is viewed / clicked.

The table has no primary or foreign keys and no relationships. 
However, when I enter some data for testing and try entering the same imgID multiple times it always appears greyed out and with a red error icon.

Usually this makes sense as you don't want duplicate records but as the purpose is different here it does make sense for me.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this or work around it ? What would be a common way to do this ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Why would you want duplicates for `imgID` if you are using this to keep track of counts?

Comment: Hi, I would like to use this as a click counter so the same image can be clicked multiple times and I do not need additional data here that would make a record unique. So if e.g. the image with ID 5 gets clicked ten times I would then have ten times the same record as it is always the same image.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a timestamp to make a record unique but then I might have two people click at the same time and I would like to avoid storing additional and unneeded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your requirement to store non-unique values, simply remove primary keys, unique constraints, and unique indexes.  I expect you may still want a non-unique clustered index on ImgID to improve performance of aggregate queries that would otherwise require a scan the entire table and sort.  I suggest you store an insert timestamp, not to provide uniqueness, but to facilitate purging data by date, should the need arise in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some unique index on that table. Make sure there is no unique index and no unique or primary key constraint.

Or, SSMS simply doesn't know how to identify the row that was just inserted because it has no key.

It is generally not best practice to have a table without a (logical) primary key. In your case, I'd make the image id the primary key and increment the counter. The `MERGE` statement is well-suited for performing and insert or update at the same time. Alternatives exist.

If you don't like that, create a surrogate primary key (an identity column set as the primary key).

At the moment you have no way of addressing a specific row. That makes the table a little unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow multiple rows being absolutely identical, how would you update/delete one of those rows?
How would you expect the database being able to "know" what row you referred to??
At the very least add a separate identity column (preferred being the clustered index, too).

As a side note: It's weird that you *"like to avoid unneeded data"* but at the same time insert duplicates over and over again instead of simply add up the click count per single image...

Comment: Thanks. This would only be used as a log so I would never have to update or delete anything here. How would I add up the click count instead ?

Comment: A log that would never be deleted?? Do you have access to never ending storage space? What does your concept look like to archive your log data? To Update the click count look up MERGE as usr already recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL statements, not GUI, if the table has not primary key or unique constraint.